# Linear optimization - can't find my mistake (simplex method , setting up the table)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

\begin{align}
&x_1 -2x_4 + 4x_5  = 1\\
&x_2 + x_4~~~~~~~~~~~~~= 1\\
&x_3 + 3x_4 + 2x_5  = 4\\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x\geq 0\\
6-2x_1+x_2-x_3&+4x_4-9x_5 \to \max
\end{align}
So, first I transformed the function :

$z= 6 - 2x_1 + x_2 -x_3 + 4x_4 - 9x_5$

$z-6 = -2x_1 + x_2 -x_3 + 4x_4 - 9x_5$

let $t = (z-6)$

$t =  2x_1 + x_2 -x_3 + 4x_4 - 9x_5$

I got the following table

[image]

The problem is that after manipulating the table I get that $t= 4$ and $z =10$ (the maximum) which does not seem to be correct...

Is this the right way to set up the table? Thank you!

P.S.: I used the following algorithm for the table

http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/4e/shared/downloads/c09s3.pdf

Comment: oops, I edited it (that does not change the entries in the table though)

Comment: I typed in :

Maximize p = 6-2*x1+x2-x3+4*x4-9*x5  subject to

x1 - 2*x4 + 4*x5 = 1

x2 + x4 =1

x3 + 3*x4 + 2*x5 = 4

But I get an error
 'Sorry, I can't process this.
 Press 'Example' for general information'

Comment: I still get the same error... could you send me a screenshot of how you did it?